# how to use multiple mochacov reporters in single Gruntfile and get the coverage report

Tags: gruntjs

Currently am switching between html-cov and json-cov in my gruntfile and running the command

```
grunt mochacov:all > coverage.html
```

(or)

```
grunt mochacov:all > coverage.json
```

Here is the json portion of config from my Gruntfile.js :

```
mochacov : {
  options : {
    reporter : 'json-cov',
    //reporter : 'travis-cov',
    require : ['should'],
    timeout: 250000,
    //quiet : true,
    output : 'coverage.json',
  },
  all: ['test/test-*.js']
},
```

Is there anyway using which i can get both coverage.html and coverage.json in the output by default by specifying both html-cov and json-cov somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the answer for the same :-

This is what we need to have in our Gruntfile.js

```
mochacov: {           
      jsoncoverage: {
        options: {
          reporter: 'json-cov',
          //reporter : 'travis-cov',
          require: ['should'],
          timeout: 250000,
          //quiet : true,
          output: 'reports/coverage.json'
        },
        all: ['test/test-*.js']
      },
      htmlcoverage: {
        options: {
          reporter: 'html-cov',
          //reporter : 'travis-cov',
          require: ['should'],
          timeout: 250000,
          //quiet : true,
          output: 'reports/coverage.html'
        },
        all: ['test/test-*.js']
      }
    }

//and then the following line needs to be there :

grunt.registerTask('mochacoverage', ['mochacov:jsoncoverage', 'mochacov:htmlcoverage']);
```

Then we can run it using grunt mochacoverage and it will do both html and json

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, looks like by default grunt-mocha-cov doesn't support this, as the reporter only accepts a 'string' ([per the docs](https://github.com/mmoulton/grunt-mocha-cov)).

Theoretically this should be possible with a grunt multitask.